# Very long distance Ethernet connection for internet and other data (2000 feet)

Tags: ethernet

I am building a house. It's located about 2000 feet away from the nearest internet cable.  I had to run our electrical service underground the whole way, and have already installed a conduit for internet/phone cables from end to end with pull points every 1000 feet.

My question is: what's a cost-effective way to establish a reliable, high-speed Ethernet connection at this distance?  It will be used to provide internet service as well as video/audio feeds and control signals.  I think 100 Mbps each direction would be satisfactory as a target maximum speed for the connection.

We will have electrical power available at both ends of the connection.

I have looked into Ethernet extenders, but the maximum speed seems to drop drastically as the distance increases.

I would love to use fiber, but I can't find an inexpensive termination method.

I don't think wireless is practical because we don't have line-of-sight between the endpoints due to a large area of trees.

A satellite or 4G connection is not suitable due to price, speed, and reliability, plus the need for audio/video/control signals across the distance.

**UPDATE 2016:**

I installed RG6 gel-filled direct-bury coax cable (in PVC conduit for added protection) and used Ethernet-to-coax extenders ([TrendNet TPA-311](https://www.trendnet.com/products/coax-extender/TPA-311)) and am VERY pleased with the results.  At a cost of $50 or less per device, it's very reasonable cost. Also, RG6 coax, if you shop around, is very cheap.

I am able to achieve 60Mbit internet speed (which is my ISP's maximum offering in my area) and these devices are very stable - no crashes or need to reboot them.  I even installed a T to split the line halfway in order to connect another building to the network.

One very important note: **Be sure** to install high quality grounded surge protection at EACH termination point.  I used [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0016AIYU6).  I tried the system without surge protection, and within a week my TPA-311 devices were destroyed.  I disassembled them to diagnose the problem and found several components vaporized due to a high energy event.  **Lesson learned.**  Since installing surge protection, we've had several large lightning storms and we're still working rock solid.

Other installation notes:

- Get a cheap coax crimper and bulk coax terminators.  They are very easy to install. No need for any expensive tools.
- For long pulls, a cable lubricant is absolutely essential.  Our first pull of about 800 feet was without lubricant, and I began to doubt we would ever make it.  Subsequent pulls (even longer distances) with lubricant were easy.

**Update after 1.5 years** - still working perfectly!  Have not needed to replace any components (except a battery in my UPS).  Very pleased with this solution!

**Update after 5 years** - still working perfectly!

Comment: Define inexpensive and please do tell us at what did you look exactly? Fiber is the only real way that I see. Also, modern Ethernet connections are full-duplex, so you get same speed both ways. There are media converters for gigabit fiber, for example TP-Link MC210CS that are in the $50-60 range.

Comment: I will second the vote for fiber.  Termination is usually handled by a telecom company that has the equipment (you wouldn't buy it for one time use).  Once terminated you shouldn't have to deal with it again.  Choose your termination form factor such as ST or SC and use a media converter to convert to copper gigabit Ethernet.

Comment: Since the run is entirely on my property past the d-mark, the telco would not touch it.  Thus I have to do everything myself.  Thus an inexpensive termination (sub $20 USD per termination) would be the goal.

Comment: I think the coax solution proposed below by @bigjosh is the most reasonable, due to the cost of coax cable, the ease of termination, and reasonable price of extender hardware.  Would love to have fiber, but due to the high cost of connector termination installation (i.e. cleaving tool, etc) I think it's not practical for me :(

Comment: Belden's FX Brilliance tool-less terminators might work, but could I cut/polish the fiber with common household tools? (http://www.belden.com/docs/upload/FX-Brilliance-Universal_-Connectors_Brochure.PDF)

Comment: Will a cleaver like this (http://www.amazon.com/RioRand-RR-FC-6S-Optical-Cleaver-SUMITOMO/dp/B00HE10U3K/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1424451610&sr=8-3&keywords=fiber+cleaver) actually even work?  I thought they were upward of $2000 USD.  This one is only $57!

Comment: Ryan, I would love for you to elaborate a bit. I'm getting ready to do the same exact thing but I'm only going 1000 ft.
Where you put the surge protectors?
What type of connectors you used and where (male/female ends)?
Where did you put the extender?

Comment: You came back twice after more than a year to let others know how your solution worked out? More people should do that! Have a +1

Comment: @Sarah  Be sure to read the manual on the Ethernet-over-coax extender to ensure you have a clear understanding of the layout.  You need an extender device at each endpoint of the coax.  Buy some high quality RG6 coax flood filled with silicone gel.  Install inside PVC conduit if possible (use lots of cable lube to and a pull-string to install the coax).  Use male F-type compression connectors and get yourself a good crimper tool.  Install a surge suppressor at each end of the coax before it enters the repeater devices and be sure to ground the suppressors properly.

Comment: Use female-to-female adapters if you need to join lengths of cable.  I brought the conduit out of the ground every 500 feet for splices using large radius elbows, then I placed a 4" PVC pipe and cap over the spliced sections to protect them.  Use F-type connectors with rubber boots for extra water ingress protection.

Comment: You will need AC power at each end of the coax, and you will need a dry, ventilated enclosure to house your equipment, as well as surge protection for the AC lines, an ethernet router, your internet modem, etc. Battery backup is handy too.

Comment: @JRE I'm unsure why you chose to lowercase Internet in your edit; the capitalized spelling is widely accepted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want an Ethernet over coax extender like this one...

[https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Gigabit-Ethernet-Unmanaged-Extender/dp/B00AMCKN80/ref=as_sl_pc_ss_til?tag=joshcom-20&linkCode=w01&linkId=B6C47PTXNGHWHVUT&creativeASIN=B00AMCKN80](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AMCKN80)

It should easily be able get you to 100Mbps @ 2000ft (~600 meters) using any supported coax cable...

[image: cable/disance/speed chart]

Comment: Thanks for the info.  However the problem with that type is that as the distance increases, the speed decreases.  Per their spec, at 300m the max speed is 75Mbit/s, and 1km it drops to 10Mbit/s.

Comment: I did find this one, which may offer higher speeds: http://www.ethernetextender.com/ethernet-extension-products/ethernet-extension-dslam/850.php?gclid=CIWW1pO47sMCFYU-aQodb38ABA

Comment: The speed depends on range and cable quality. If you have room in the conduit, you should be able to get 112Mbps @ 2000 feet over RG-11 cable. The length/speed/distance chart for the coax model is available at http://sgcdn.startech.com/005329/media/sets/EOC1110x_Manual/EOC1110x.pdf.

Comment: I like the idea of the coax-based solution.  1) coax is cheap! 2) I can fit multiple RG6 cables in my 1/2" conduit 3) 144Mbps at ~600m with RG6 looks *well* within spec. 4) the extender hardware seems reasonably priced.  THANKS!

Comment: Sorry to revive a 6-year-old thread, but I was wondering if you have any kind of update about what solution you went with and what your experience has been?

Answer (score 4):

[100Base-FX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet#100BASE-FX) seems to be right with 2km as its max theoretic distance, and there appear to be [converters](http://www.netstoredirect.com/trendnet-media-converters/44053-trendnet-tfc-110msc-network-media-converter-0710931504163.html?gclid=CJCyv-e57sMCFeHKtAodHXoAiw) available at reasonable prices. Or is the termination problem one of attaching the connectors to the end of the fiber? I would have thought it was possible to just order one of the correct length.

Comment: Yes the termination (attaching the connectors) is the problem. Trying to pull the cable through the conduit with ends attached would probably damage it.  May not even fit, due to size of conduit.

Comment: @Ryan Griggs Do research connector types. There's a whole science about that and what's compatible with what, but there are any connectors that have exterior protection for the fiber core and that are same size or smaller than regular 8P8C connector. For example DIN optical connector is very small and then you can get an adapter from that to whatever you want to use in the end.

Comment: I see termination kits for < $100 on Ali, but don't know how well they work.

Comment: You can buy pre-terminated fiber lengths that are designed to be pulled through ducts. On the ones I bought there was a short section of hoze that covered the connectors. On one end of the hose was a pulling eye, on the other end was an adaptor peice that screwed to the gland on the cable. This gland was in turn bonded to the kevlar reinforcements in the cable.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is a practical approach, but maybe you could use power over ethernet repeaters.

One unit typically extends the range by 100m, I've seen one advertised to be chainable six times, so you would get 600m, which is quite close to the 2000ft (it was the [ALLNET ALL048600](http://www.allnet.de/at/allnet-brand/produkte/poe/poe-adapter/p/allnet-all048600-poe-gigabit-repeater-poe-90w/), sorry I only found a German description). Maybe you could provide power from both sides, to easily bridge that distance.

This would also allow gigabit ethernet.

But you would have to buy 6 repeaters - and install them somehow along the line. Doesn't sound like the most reliable solution.

Comment: I can't chain due to no breaks in the conduit.  I only have two pull points, each at about 1000 feet.  Otherwise, the conduit is buried about 2.5 feet deep.  But thanks for the info!

Comment: Oh dear, I read something along the line of every 100 feet (missed a zero there) a pull point... never mind my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have power at the remote end and an approximation of line of sight, Wifi and a yagi at each end would be a fraction of the cost of a cabling run.

Comment: As stated, no line of sight due to heavily wooded area.

Comment: @RyanGriggs Maybe you can wireless hop for part of the distance, from home to the trees or the trees to the cable?

Comment: Everything is underground, don't want antennas in the middle of the field. Also would have to run at least 75% of the run to get around the trees. Thanks